# Android HTTP POST to get response without JSON, and put in Toast

Tags: android, url, http-post

I wanted to test if my Android app can sucessfully get the response from a php page, without JSON. The php just contains `echo "hello";`, but I failed to Toast it. Closest solution I can find is, where I tried to put some parts of it into my code: [How can I view the string sent from httppost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150044/how-can-i-view-the-string-sent-from-httppost)

My code as below (updated):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Threaded", "Inside thread!!!");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.10/fyp/test.php");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                Log.i("Connect", content.toString());

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                Log.i("Connect", sb.toString());

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        showToastMessage("hello");       
                      }
                    });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Connect", "Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
}
```

The thread seems not running, where the line `Log.i("Threaded", "Inside thread!!!");` is not showing in LogCat, which part am I doing wrongly? Note: handler has been declare in the class.

Comment: Please post the stack trace if you can 
so that we can know what the error is

Comment: The "error" is I can't toast the "hello", where I guess the answer is stated as @Nicklas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you perform the toast on the UI thread or else it will fail.
Either use a Handler or wrap your network operation in a AsyncTask where you pass the result to the onPostExecute method which is processed by the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

If this is not your problem, add logging to see that you get a response from the server and check your LogCat for the "hello"

Comment: I guess that's the problem, I did not use a handler, where I treated it like receiving location data. I tried to log, and it did not show anything, maybe I logged it wrongly? I put `Log.i("Connect", sb.toString());` after the while loop, and it did not appear in LogCat.

Comment: could you give me a sample on how Handler should be use in this context? From the codes I browsed, it seems they are using Handler+Message+Bundle, but I have no idea how to use the Bundle with the response message, "hello".

Comment: You don't need to use messages or Bundle.
Instantiate the handler with the activity thread then invoke the handler.post() with a new Runnable, within the runnable perform the toast. Done. :P

Comment: Add logging just after you get the response to see that you made a successful post also. And if you have connection problem it could take as long as 30 seconds before it times out and the exception is logged.

Comment: I have updated my code on question, I failed to get it working. If I removed the thread, NetworkOnMainThread exception is thrown, but if I put back the thing, the thread seems not running.

Comment: As stated before, add logging to assert that the POST is successful so that you at least know that this part is working.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand you. Without creating new thread, I can log for `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.10/fyp/test.php");`, but further statements thrown exception (NetworkOnMainThread), so I can't get the POST response. If I create new thread, I can't even log a single thing. Not even `Log.i("Threaded", "Inside thread!!!");`

Comment: Do you invoke t.start(); ?

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about that! Silly me! Thanks dude, I got it working now! I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: I guess you wont do that again ;) No problem, merry Christmas!:P